# How to Find Companies that Does not have 1 Employee that Did a Search?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to figure out how to write a sql statement (then I need to convert it to EF Core Lambda after which I not sure how to do either) that will solve my problem.

**Problem**

Must find all Inactive Companies in the last x days filtered by certain "TrackingEvents"

Tables

```
Companies
- Id
- Name

Branches
- Id
- Name
- CompanyId

Employees 
- Id
- Name
- BranchId

Tracking
- Id
- EmployeeId (nullable...there is tracking for non members)
- Name
- TrackingEventId

TrackingEvents
- Id
-Name
```

**Attempt**

```
SELECT        Companies.Name
FROM            Branches INNER JOIN
                         Companies ON Branches.CompanyId = Companies.Id INNER JOIN
                         Employees ON Branches.Id = Employees.BranchId Left JOIN
                         Trackings ON Employees.Id = Trackings.EmployeeId
                         where Trackings.Id IS NULL
                         group by Companies.Name
```

I have not attempted to do filtering by date or tracking event.

What I have I don't think is right as what I think it is doing is that if 1 employee in the company has not done a search then the company is returned.

what I need to do is somehow group all employees, all branches and treat it as one. So if 1 employee meets the criteria then the "company" is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns companies that have no tracking events is the last 7 days

```
select companies.Name
from Companies
left join
    (select b.CompanyID
     from branches b
     join employees e on e.branchID = b.id
     join tracking t on t.EmployeeID = e.id
     where [eventDate] > dateadd(day,-7, getdate())
     ) l on l.CompanyID=Companies.ID
where l.CompanyID is null
group by companies.Name
```

Comment: This seems to be what I need and I can build on this. Though now seeing I got even less clue how it will look like as a EF statement.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term EF Statement

Comment: Entity Framework, It's alright you might not use that technology. I think it might be pretty nasty so might just use raw sql for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct Id, Name From Companies c 
inner join Branches b on c.Id = b.CompanyId
inner join Employees  e on b.Id = e.BranchId
where not exists
(Select 1 From Tracking t where t.EmployeeId = e.Id)
```

Let me know

Comment: hmm, this seems to still shows duplicate companies. Maybe need a group by? Also I am seeing companies that have at least 1 person do some sort of event.

Comment: I have multiple Ids. So I did Companies.Id but I then get "The multi-part identifier "Companies.Id" could not be bound"

Comment: Add c.Id instead of Companies.Id. I have an alias in front for Companies

Comment: Gotcha, It seems to be still not correct. I think I see where you going with this but it results seem to be reversed as I am getting companies that I know have made 1 search.

Comment: I think it still is finding employees that have not made a search and then marking that company as a company that has done no searches.